# incremental model in dbt with struct fields

Tags: apache-spark, struct, parquet, dbt, spark-thriftserver

I'm evaluating DBT for a possible usecase, and everything seems just fine except for one single situation. This is when the source table has struct fields.

I'm using `Spark Thrift Server connector`, underlying data is stored as `parquet` in `S3`. DBT version is 0.20

This is a piece of the source table create sentence, as you can se there are struct fields in there.

```
CREATE TABLE `<someSchema>`.`<sourceTable>` (
  `properties` STRUCT<`site`: STRING>,
  `channel` STRING,
  `timestamp` STRING,
  `anotherDate` STRING,
  `aDate ` STRING)
  USING parquet
  PARTITIONED BY (aDate)
  LOCATION 's3a://<someBucket>'
```

My model just perform a select over that table with certain where clauses. First time it is run, it works just fine, it creates a table exactly the same as the original with some minor changes, just as expected, even with the struct fields.

Here is a piece of the sink table create table

```
CREATE TABLE `<someSchema>`.`dbtsink` (
      `properties` STRUCT<`site`: STRING>,
      `channel` STRING,
      `timestamp` STRING,
      `anotherDate ` STRING,
      `aDate` STRING)
USING parquet
PARTITIONED BY (anotherDate)
```

My problem comes when I run dbt again with some other values in the where clauses, it should create another partition in sink table. Query compilation is just fine

It raises this error:

```
Runtime Error in model dbtsink (models/anotherDate/dbtsink.sql)
  Database Error
    Error running query: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`site`' given input columns: [dbtsink__dbt_tmp.channel, dbtsink__dbt_tmp.anotherDate, dbtsink__dbt_tmp.aDate, dbtsink__dbt_tmp.properties, dbtsink__dbt_tmp.timestamp]; line 4 pos 25;
    'InsertIntoStatement 'UnresolvedRelation [someSchema, dbtsink], false, false
    +- 'Project [properties#6526, 'site, channel#6527, timestamp#6528, aDate#6541, anotherDate#6540]
       +- SubqueryAlias dbtsink__dbt_tmp
          +- Project [properties#6526, channel#6527, timestamp#6528, anotherDate#6540, aDate#6541]
             +- Filter (((aDate#6541 > 2021060100) AND (aDate#6541 <= 2021070609)) AND (anotherDate#6540 = 2021070609))
                +- SubqueryAlias spark_catalog.someSchema.sourceTable
                   +- Relation[context#6524,traits#6525,properties#6526,channel#6527,timestamp#6528,projectId#6529,integrations#6530,messageId#6531,originalTimestamp#6532,receivedAt#6533,sentAt#6534,userId#6535,anonymousId#6536,type#6537,providerId#6538,version#6539,anotherDate#6540,aDate#6541] parquet
```

It seems that it's trying to read or write the inner field of the struct as a root field. I tested with other struct fields and it happens the same I just want the struct as such, as in the very first execution. As I said, it only happens in the second execution.

This is my model's query, it is very simple

```
select 
properties,
channel,
timestamp,
anotherDate,
aDate
from {{ source('someSchema', 'sourceTable') }}
where aDate > '{{ var("aDateLowerLimit") }}' and aDate <= '{{ var("aDateUpperLimit") }}'
and anotherDate = '{{ var("anotherDate") }}'
```

If I change the select to convert properties from struct to json with `to_json(properties)` it works just as expected, generating a new partition.

If something wrong with structs in DBT? I am doing something wrong?

I am using incremental materialization and I tested it with append andn insert_overwrite, that didn't seem to be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to how DBT is trying to parse the columns in a Spark table using a [REGEX](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-spark/blob/b315008c039d8d30c0fed0f858c38fa77c135c9b/dbt/adapters/spark/impl.py#L229). See the [parse_columns_from_information](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-spark/blob/b315008c039d8d30c0fed0f858c38fa77c135c9b/dbt/adapters/spark/impl.py#L222-L249) function.

You can not use a REGEX for parsing a table schema. That function is using the results provided by this Spark SQL statement: `show table extended in someSchema like '*'`. When using that statement you get something like this for your table schema:

```
Schema: root
 |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- site: string (nullable = true)
 |-- channel: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- anotherDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- aDate: string (nullable = true)
```

Applying that [REGEX](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-spark/blob/b315008c039d8d30c0fed0f858c38fa77c135c9b/dbt/adapters/spark/impl.py#L229) to the above string will mess up your columns as you have experienced.

You can work around this problem using [parse_describe_extended](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-spark/blob/b315008c039d8d30c0fed0f858c38fa77c135c9b/dbt/adapters/spark/impl.py#L165). This function is using the results provided by this Spark SQL statement: `describe extended someSchema.dbtsink`. In order to use
`parse_describe_extended` you need to disable the DBT cache (something that could be harmful) For disabling the DBT cache you can use this dbt argument: `--bypass-cache`.

Comment: Summarizing, struct doesn't work with cache in DBT :( . Your solution works like a charm. Kind regards

Comment: Btw, this behaviour is fixed in DTB since August 2021 

https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-spark/pull/204